# AjaxToolKit Issues in Modal Popup in IE 10

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, internet-explorer-10, modalpopupextender

I have a following implementation in an asp.net application.

In abc.aspx i have this tag:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopUpExtender popupControlId="pnl">
<asp:Panel id="pnl">
<iframe src="example.aspx" id="fr2">
</asp:Panel>
```

Now the example.aspx has a PopUp Control Extender as like this

```
    <asp:Textbox id="txt">

    <asp:UpdatePanel id=udp>
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button/>
    <asp:CheckBoxList>
    <asp:Button/> .
    </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>


    <ajaxToolkit:PopUpControlExtender targetControlId="txt">
    </ajaxToolkit>
```

Now that PopupControlExtender in example.aspx runs fine when it is normally rendered as an aspx page.When the Page is Implemented as above in an iframe,in IE10, the PopUp Control Extender Doesnot Work as Desired.But it Works Fine In compatibility modes of IE as Well as Normal modes in Firefox,Chrome and Safari.

Please Help on this ..

Comment: I really don't understand your application concept. I don't see the **PopupControlID** setting for **PopupControlExtender**. And I don't see **TargetControlID** setting for **ModalPopUpExtender** as well. You also provide us the wrong code that couldn't run, such as <ajaxToolkit ModalPopUpExtender which should be <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopUpExtender

Comment: You also set **runat="server"** for all controls, except iframe, don't you?